# In Python, how do I use urllib to see if a website is 404 or 200?

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-codes

How to get the code of the headers through urllib?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

The getcode() method (Added in python2.6) returns the HTTP status code that was sent with the response, or None if the URL is no HTTP URL.

```
>>> a=urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/asdfsf')
>>> a.getcode()
404
>>> a=urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')
>>> a.getcode()
200
```

Comment: To use in python 3, just use `from urllib.request import urlopen`.

Comment: In python 3.4, if there is a 404, `urllib.request.urlopen` returns a `urllib.error.HTTPError`.

Comment: Doesn't work in python 2.7. If the HTTP returns 400, an exception is thrown

Answer (score 91):

You can use [urllib2](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#urlerror) as well:

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org/fish.html')
try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    if e.code == 404:
        # do something...
    else:
        # ...
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    # Not an HTTP-specific error (e.g. connection refused)
    # ...
else:
    # 200
    body = resp.read()
```

Note that [`HTTPError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError) is a subclass of `URLError` which stores the HTTP status code.

Comment: Is the second `else` a mistake?

Comment: @NadavB The exception object 'e' will look like a response object.  That is, it's file-like and you can 'read' the payload from it.

Answer (score 57):

For Python 3:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error

url = 'http://www.google.com/asdfsf'
try:
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    # Return code error (e.g. 404, 501, ...)
    # ...
    print('HTTPError: {}'.format(e.code))
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    # Not an HTTP-specific error (e.g. connection refused)
    # ...
    print('URLError: {}'.format(e.reason))
else:
    # 200
    # ...
    print('good')
```

Comment: For [URLError](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.error.html) `print(e.reason)` could be used.

Comment: What about `http.client.HTTPException`?

Comment: How can I check for a 301 or 302?

Answer (score 6):

```
import urllib2

try:
    fileHandle = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/fish.html')
    data = fileHandle.read()
    fileHandle.close()
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print 'you got an error with the code', e
```

Comment: TIMEX is interested in grabbing the http request code (200, 404, 500, etc) not a generic error thrown by urllib2.