# How to get status code for urllib2 in python 2.7

Tags: python

How do I get status code in python 2.7 for urllib2? I dont want to use requests. I need urllib2.

```
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    print request.getcode()
    contents = json.loads(contents) 

     <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError('getcode',), <traceback object at 0x7f6238792b48>
```

Thanks

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1726434/736937)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just take a step back:

```
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
contents = result.read()
print result.getcode()
```

Answer (score 6):

use `getcode()`

```
>>> import urllib
>>> a=urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/asdfsf')
>>> a.getcode()
404
>>>
```

for `urllib2`

```
try:
    urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/asdfsf')
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.code
```

will print

```
404
```

Comment: This answer assummes that the `urllib` method doesn't throw an exception. But it does. I tried to open a url that returns error code 401 (Unauthorized) and it threw an exception on the `urlopen` call.